# Codeigniter form validation set rules

Tags: php

I am having an issue with this code:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|callback_user_check');
```

It is displaying the `user_check` error even when the username field is empty; I was expecting the required error message.

```
function username() {
    $query = "SELECT salt FROM user WHERE username = ?";
    $get_query = $this->db->query($query, array($this->username));
    if ($get_query->num_rows() > 0) {
        $row = $get_query->row_array();
        return $row['salt'];
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: show the `user_check` function

Comment: Post call back function too here

Comment: function username()
{
    $query = "SELECT salt FROM user WHERE username = ?";
    $get_query = $this->db->query($query, array($this->username));
    if ($get_query->num_rows() > 0) {
        $row = $get_query->row_array();
        return $row['salt'];
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

Comment: Don't post your code in comments—post it in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Set validation custom message

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('username', 'Your message here');
```